# on Edittext, the talkback announces maximum limit Reached, even if it is not reached This happens when maxLength is defined along with numberPassword

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

[Accessibility][Talkback]  I make some tests with TalkBack to read input text to make my app more accessible. I find this possible accessibility bug of Edittext.

When I use the component Edittext with "numberPassword" and "maxLength" defined. the TalkBack, read  "maximum limit Reached" but in actual maximum limit is not hit.

This bug is reproducible in:

Reproducible on: Google pixel 3(OS v11), Samsung s 10 e(OS v10)

Works fine on: Samsung s8(OS v8), Samsung s 10 (OS v10)

Can anyone help how to resolve this?

Comment: If this is a bug, file a bug report, at the moment you haven't actually asked a question :-P

Comment: I have updated the question, basically, I need someone to help me to resolve this.

Comment: @ChetakBhimani Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Dr.jacky  Please check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172107685

Answer (score 0):

recently, I had meet the same problem, after reaching the issuer in the comment and searching the resource. I find the solution.

first of all,  we have to import the `com.google.material` component, it would be better to use the latest version, if you can not, please make sure it above the `1.4`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

second of all, we have to choose to use the `TextInputEditText`;

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="3"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```